# Query not producing what its supposed to

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following two tables:

Table Authors:

```
AuthorID  Name
A         John
B         Alex
C         Carl
```

Table AuthorsCompatibility:

```
AuthorID1    AuthorID2    Compatibility
A            B            5.0
A            C            4.0
B            C            4.5
```

I want to produce the following:

```
AuthorID1   Name1    AuthorID2   Name2   Compatibility
A           John     B           Alex    5.0
A           John     C           Carl    4.0
B           Alex     C           Carl    4.5
```

This is what I tried, but I know it's not working:

```
select AuthorID1, A.Name, AuthorID2, B.Name, Compatibility
from AuthorsCompatibility, Authors as A, Authors as B
where AuthorID1=A.AuthorID and AuthorID2=B.AuthorID
```

Comment: What is your current result?

Comment: Why is it not working? What error do you get? Apart from archaic syntax, there is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are 2 different products, pls remove the product tag you do not use

Comment: I have tried your query it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not joining correctly (you're using the very old style joins). Try joins like this below;

```
SELECT
    ac.AuthorID1
    ,a1.Name AS Name1
    ,ac.AuthorID2
    ,a2.Name AS Name2
    ,ac.Compatibility
FROM AuthorsCompatibility ac
INNER JOIN Authors a1
    ON ac.AuthorID1 = a1.AuthorID
INNER JOIN Authors a2
    ON ac.AuthorID2 = a2.AuthorID
```

Using this sample data;

```
CREATE TABLE Authors (AuthorID nvarchar(1), Name nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO Authors
VALUES
('A', 'John')
,('B', 'Alex')
,('C', 'Carl')

CREATE TABLE AuthorsCompatibility (AuthorID1 nvarchar(1), AuthorID2 nvarchar(1), Compatibility money)
INSERT INTO AuthorsCompatibility (AuthorID1, AuthorID2, Compatibility)
VALUES
('A', 'B', 5.0)
,('A', 'C', 4.0)
,('B', 'C', 4.5)
```

Gives this result;

```
AuthorID1   Name1   AuthorID2   Name2   Compatibility
A           John    B           Alex    5.00
A           John    C           Carl    4.00
B           Alex    C           Carl    4.50
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ac.AuthorID1, a.Name, ac.AuthorID2, b.Name, ac.Compatibility
FROM AuthorsCompatibility ac
INNER JOIN AUTHORS a ON ac.AuthorID1 = a.AuthorID
INNER JOIN AUTHORS b ON ac.AuthorID2 = b.AuthorID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite it in JOIN-form like this

```
select ac.AuthorID1, A.Name, ac.AuthorID2, B.Name, ac.Compatibility
  from AuthorsCompatibility ac
  join Authors as A
    on ac.AuthorID1 = A.AuthorID
  join Authors as B
    on ac.AuthorID2 = B.AuthorID
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried your query and it works properly:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Authors (AuthorID nvarchar(1), Name nvarchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Authors
VALUES
('A', 'John')
,('B', 'Alex')
,('C', 'Carl')

CREATE TABLE #AuthorsCompatibility (AuthorID1 nvarchar(1), AuthorID2 nvarchar(1), Compatibility money)
INSERT INTO #AuthorsCompatibility (AuthorID1, AuthorID2, Compatibility)
VALUES
('A', 'B', 5.0)
,('A', 'C', 4.0)
,('B', 'C', 4.5)

select 
    AuthorID1, A.Name, AuthorID2, B.Name, Compatibility
from #AuthorsCompatibility, #Authors as A, #Authors as B
where AuthorID1=A.AuthorID and AuthorID2=B.AuthorID

drop table #AuthorsCompatibility,#Authors
```

Comment: It's generally frowned upon to use somebody else's sample data in your own response to the same question.

Comment: I haven't given solution to OP just inform that his/her query working. I haven't write my query because mean while i got statement for insert values